# Bash - Prepare command in cli without executing it

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm working on a bash script that lets the user configure a number of settings (like for example the current driver or list of drivers, the current release, the current test suite, the current compiler or list of compilers, etc) and which works with a number of tools (compilers, misra analyzer, test report creator, etc). The script defines some aliases like for example: compile, test, misra, report, etc. When such an alias is run by the user, the script prepares about 1-3 sample commands that can be run with that tool and echoes the sample commands on the screen like for example:

```
s1 = misra current_driver current_compiler
s2 = misra current_drivers_list current_compiler
s3 = misra current_drivers_list current_compilers_list
```

The user looks at the samples, chooses the most appropriate, types s1, s2 or s3 
and hits Enter. The script adds the selected command in the history, as top command. The user presses 'up arrow' and has the command ready to be **edited** if needed and executed when everything is ok, at a hit of Enter key.

Now, I want to speed up the process of selecting the command, by getting rid of that 'up arrow key' press. What I would like to accomplish is: when user types s1, s2 or s3 and hits Enter, the corresponding command is added in the command line, without being executed. The thing is that I want to obtain the same behavior like the command would have been typed by the user, meaning the user should still be able to edit it, before launching it by pressing Enter.
   Is there any method I can use to implement this behavior ?

Thank you

Comment: Might be related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52578/execute-a-readline-function-without-keybinding

Comment: `bash` has no way of programmatically populating the command line directly. You might play with the `read` command and the `-i` option, then use `eval` to execute the result.

Comment: There is a question related to this somewhere on Stack Overflow, because I know I've either provided an answer similar to what I describe above, or at least referenced the `print -z` command provided by `zsh`, which *does* do exactly what you want.